# Wrap matched string inside separate <TAG>

Tags: jquery

I have a string in a div, and an input box where in the user can type the values. What I want is, if the user types "some" in the `<input>`, since the string already contains "some", I would want to put that "some" in a different `<tag>`, like `<div>this is <i>some</i>string!</div>`

```
<div>this is some string!</div>
```

I tried to identify the match userinput string in the `<div>` using `indexOf()`, not sure if it were the right way or not. Below is the fiddle link (incomplete fiddle). Need tips as to how to get done with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var replaced_string;
        var str_to_replace;
        var current_string;
        $('#text_inp').keyup(function () {
            str_to_replace = $('#text_inp').val();
            current_string = $('#div_test').text();
            var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + str_to_replace + ')\\b', 'gim');
            replaced_string = current_string.replace(regex, '<i style="color:red">$1</i>');
            $('#div_test').html(replaced_string)
        });
    });
```

html code

```
 <div id="div_test">this is some string!

Ever needed custom formatted sample / test data, like, bad? Well, that's the idea of this script. It's a free, open source tool written in JavaScript, PHP and MySQL that lets you quickly generate large volumes of custom data in a variety of formats for use in testing software, populating databases, and... so on and so forth.

This site offers an online demo where you're welcome to tinker around to get a sense of what the script does, what features it offers and how it works. Then, once you've whet your appetite, there's a free, fully functional, GNU-licensed version available for download. Alternatively, if you want to avoid the hassle of setting it up on your own server, you can donate $20 or more to get an account on this site, letting you generate up to 5,000 records at a time (instead of the maximum 100), and let you save your data sets. Click on the Donate tab for more information. 


</div>

<input  type="text" id="text_inp"/>
```

Comment: Hi Shriya, thanks for the code. Works great! Just curious on "\\b", where i get that "\b" is to match the character at the end or beinging, but what is extra "\" for?\

Answer (score 1):

Use replace function:

```
str_to_replace = 'some';
current_string = 'this is some string!';
replaced_string = current_string.replace(str_to_replace, '<i>' + str_to_replace + '</i>');
```

If you want to prevent wrapping of string multiple times then use:

```
str_to_replace = 'some';
current_string = 'this is some string!';

// check if we already have wrapped str_to_replace in the i tag
if( current_string.indexOf('<i>' + str_to_replace  + '</i>') == -1 )  {
    replaced_string = current_string.replace( str_to_replace, '<i>' + str_to_replace + '</i>' );
}
```

Comment: What will happen when the user again type the word some?? One more li tag will be added.right??

Comment: @ShriyaR Thanks, I have updated the code above for such a situation

Comment: @saqib amin is this code replace all the some word if the div contains more than one some word??

Comment: No It will replace only one occurrence